# Ethereum web3 callback with parameters

Tags: javascript, callback, ethereum, solidity, web3js

I'm interacting with my solidity contract via web3js in JavaScript and I have the following functions:

```js
// An investor buys tokens for ether
    function buyTokens(account) {
        document.getElementById("transaktion").innerText = "Transaction is going to be executed.";
            web3.personal.unlockAccount(web3.eth.accounts[account], '******');
            contract_instance.buy({from: web3.eth.accounts[account], value: document.getElementById('value').value}, function(error, result) {
                if(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                } else {
                    var txHash = result;
                    console.log(txHash);
                    callWhenMined(txHash, getTokenBalance);                          
    }
    
    function callWhenMined(txHash, callback) {
        web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, function(error, rcpt) {
            if(error) {
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                if(rcpt == null) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        callWhenMined(txHash, callback);
                    }, 500);
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("transaktion").innerText = "";               
                    callback();
                }
            }
        })
    }

    // Gets the token balance
    function getTokenBalance(id, account) {
        document.getElementById(id).innerText = contract_instance.getMyInvestorBalance({from: web3.eth.accounts[account]});                   
    }
```

If a user wants to buy tokens for ether (which in Solidity is a non constant function) the transaction needs to get mined. So the function buyTokens(account) calls the function callWhenMined(txHash, callback) which checks every 500ms if the transaction got mined. When it did get mined callback() is going to be called which leads to the problem: callback() calls getTokenBalance() which needs two parameters (the id of the documents element and the account number) so the callback function will fail.

But if I would invoke callWhenMined(txHash, getTokenBalance('testID', 1)); for example like that then I would get the error that callback is not a function. I do understand that this doesn't work like that because callback() doenst take parameters.

So my question is: Is there a way to have the function callWhenMined which takes in the parameters of the function which needs to get invoked? something like this?

```js
function callWhenMined(txHash, callback(param1, param2, ...))  {
    web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(txHash, function(error, rcpt) {
        if(error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            if(rcpt == null) {
                setTimeout(function() {
                    callWhenMined(txHash, callback);
                }, 500);
            } else {
                document.getElementById("transaktion").innerText = "";               
                callback(param1, param2, ...);
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Is that possible?